# Set the orientation when I click back button

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 screen on first screen I have set landscape orientation and on second screen I applied portrait orientation when I pop the 2nd screen and come back to first screen orientation still set as portrait how can I solve this issue where should I put these line of code so I get my orientation back when I come to home screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(
      MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: won(),
  ));
}
class won extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft, DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight]);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => won1()),
            );
          },
          child: Text('Forward'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class won1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Back'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I handled it successfully, by using RouteObserver (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html)
When navigating use this to pass screenname:

```
Navigator.of(context)
        .push(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => w,
            settings: RouteSettings(name: w.runtimeType.toString())))
        .then((value) {
      if (value == null) {
        widget.getHomepageData();
      }
    });
```

Then detect and handle screen change (forward or backward navigation), by adding observer to MaterialApp:

```
return MaterialApp(
                    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                      return MediaQuery(
                        data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
                            textScaleFactor: 1.0),
                        child: child,
                      );
                    },
                    home: GeneralStatelessWidget((ctx) => getHome(ctx)),
                    navigatorObservers: [
                      CustomRouteObserver()
            ],
                    onGenerateTitle: generateAppTitle);
```

And this is the custom observer:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tangerine/utils/flutter_device_type.dart';
import 'package:tangerine/utils/screen_functions.dart';

class CustomRouteObserver extends RouteObserver<PageRoute<dynamic>> {
  void _sendScreenView(PageRoute<dynamic> route) {
    var screenName = route.settings.name;
    final landscapeOnlyOnTablet = [
      "LandingPage",
      "/",
      "ProductScreen",
      "SearchScreen"
    ];
    if (landscapeOnlyOnTablet.contains(screenName)) {
      if (Device.get().isTablet) {
        allowLandscape();
      } else {
        denyLandscape();
      }
    } else {
      allowLandscape();
    }
  }

  @override
  void didPush(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
    super.didPush(route, previousRoute);
    if (route is PageRoute) {
      _sendScreenView(route);
    }
  }

  @override
  void didReplace({Route<dynamic> newRoute, Route<dynamic> oldRoute}) {
    super.didReplace(newRoute: newRoute, oldRoute: oldRoute);
    if (newRoute is PageRoute) {
      _sendScreenView(newRoute);
    }
  }

  @override
  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
    super.didPop(route, previousRoute);
    if (previousRoute is PageRoute && route is PageRoute) {
      _sendScreenView(previousRoute);
    }
  }
}

void allowLandscape() {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
}

void denyLandscape() {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
}
```